# Displaying information in TF

Tags: ros, ubuntu, rostopic, ros-groovy, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working on ros and I am getting as output the parameters of satellite changing constantly. When I do
`rostopic echo /topic_name`
I get the output of sattelite parameters changing constantly. rostopic tells me that I have successfully published data to the my topic. How can I use this to display my sattelite in TF. Do i have to make a brodcaster/listener or can I do it with adding a node in my launch file like

```
  node pkg="tf" type="tf_echo" name="tf_whatever" args="0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 /topic_name" />
```

I am not sure whether this addition to launch file is correct. Any help would be appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/68302/displaying-information-in-tf/) by [Gudjohnson](https://answers.ros.org/users/5370/gudjohnson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 100 on 2013-07-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe in this case you will need to create a tf brocaster, which maps your satellite pose's into tf messages.

C++: http://ros.org/wiki/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20broadcaster%20%28C%2B%2B%29

Python: http://ros.org/wiki/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20broadcaster%20%28Python%29

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2013-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3